# Ubuntu broken locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, locale

I have strange issue with my locale

except printing symbols like `[]` i have got `ÆÅ` `|` i have got`ø` and many more others

i have tried to reconfigure locales in ubuntu with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` it did't help

also tried to set up LANG env variable, nothing works for me

in terminal

```
locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

also inside files all special symbols broken

How to fix it?

Comment: I suspect the terminal font you are using is not capable of displaying what you want. Since you configured `en_US.UTF-8` as you locale did you make sure to use a UTF8 capable terminal plus compatible font?

Comment: Also, the `LANG` variable determines the locale category for native language, local customs and coded character set in the absence of the `LC_ALL` and other `LC_*`. So defining the `LC_*` ones is enough.

Comment: Try using another terminal app like `Terminator`.
If the problem still persists, its a System level error else you might just need to reset your `Terminal settings` only.